# PostgreSQL Select from an array inside an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column (locations) populated with something like below.

```
{
  "unique_id": "1",
  "address": {
    "street_address": "100 Main St",
    "city": "Pleasantville",
    "state_province": "IL",
    "country_code": "US"
  }
}
```

I know how to select "unique_id" with

```
SELECT locations #>> '{unique_id}'
FROM table;
```

But how would you select, say, "street_address"?

Comment: That doesn't look like an array at all, more like JSON(B) object? Please post your table definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options; because the JSON operators return JSON you can chain the operators:

`SELECT locations -> 'address' -> 'street_address' AS way1 FROM testjson;`

Alternatively you can use the operators that accept an array:

`SELECT locations #> '{address,street_address}' AS otherway FROM testjson;`

See this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/de4d2/6) for a working example or the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html) for further information.